# How to use bindings in another assembly with StructureMap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have a MVC (4) application and in assembly A I have this in my global.asax (in Application_Start()):

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
{
    x.For<IPerson>().Use<Person>();
    x.For<IObjectCreator>().Use<StructureMapObjectCreator>();
    x.For<IPersonRepository>().Use<PersonRepository>();
});
```

This works in assemby A.

Now, I have assembly B. Assembly B is also a web application and has a reference to assembly A. The defined bindings in assembly A must by accessible from assembly B. So, when I use IPerson in assembly B I want to use the binding from assembly A.

I've tried several things in assembly B, but I can;t figure it out. This is my last attempt:

Global.asax in assembly B (in Application_Start()):

```
var mainAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IObjectCreator));

ObjectFactory.Configure(x => 
{
    x.For<IProduct>().Use<Product>();
    x.Scan(assembly =>
    {
        assembly.Assembly(mainAssembly);
    });
});
```

What do I have to do to use the bindings from assembly A in assembly B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Registry in assembly A containing all of the mappings you need in assembly A. You could then register that Registry with assembly A in Global.asax and with assembly B in its Global.asax. [StructureMap Registry DSL](http://docs.structuremap.net/RegistryDSL.htm)

Then, in Assembly B you can register your Registry like this:

```
var container = new Container(x =>
        {
            x.AddRegistry<AssemblyARegistry>();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don;t get it completely. When I've created the registry, do I need to scan assemblies in assembly B? Or do I have to use the custom derived registry class?

Comment: Thnx for the update. I am wondering, is there another way to achieve this? This sounds like a time-consuming activity and I have to create a lot of additional registry classes. Is there a way that I only specify the bindings in assembly A and I can reuse these bindings in assembly b?

Comment: I would have thought the opposite - you would basically move the bindings from your global.asax into a Registry class (you can add all the bindings in a single Registry class) and then add it from Assembly A and Assembly B

Comment: Wow, thanks! I didn't think of putting all the bindings in one registry class :) You're right, this makes things easier to share common registries across multiple assemblies :)